# Error while viewing PDF document in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to view PDF/doc/img file in browser but getting error:

> Unable to load PDF document

**Code:**

```
private readonly IServiceContext _ctx;
public void View(string guid)
{
    var stream = null as Stream;
    repo.GetFileStream(fileName, filePath, out stream);
    if (stream.CanSeek)
    {
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    }
    _ctx.reqObj.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    _ctx.reqObj.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
    _ctx.reqObj.HttpContext.Response.Body = stream;
}
```

**Repo:**

```
public void GetFileStream(string fileName, string filePath, out Stream stream)
{
    stream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(filePath, fileName)))
    {
        if (fileStream.CanSeek) fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        fileStream.CopyTo(stream);
    }
}
```

**Browser Request:**

[image]

I just want to allow user to view the content of file in browser and not **DOWNLOAD**.

I will appreciate any help:)

**Update :** 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Content length of response is zero (0) according to response headers in image. Start by checking there. Consider adding the header.

Comment: is `public void View(string guid)` the controller action or a support method?

Comment: @Nkosi It is the suport method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content length of the response is zero (0) according to response headers in the provided image.

Consider adding the header to the response.

```
public void View(string guid) {
    var stream = null as Stream;
    repo.GetFileStream(fileName, filePath, out stream);
    if (stream.CanSeek) {
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    }
    var response = _ctx.reqObj.HttpContext.Response;
    response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"inline; filename={filename}");
    response.Headers.Add("Content-Length", stream.Length.ToString());
    response.Body = stream;
}
```

If the content length is still zero then you would need to review that the file being loaded has actual content to be read.

Comment: I am getting error on this line("Content-Length", stream.Length) : Cannot convert from long to Microsoft.Entensions.Primitives.StringValues

Comment: @User just convert it to a string.

Comment: I updated my question in which it shows the length of stream

Comment: I have added contentlength header and i am getting length also in browser.See my updated question but still same as mention in the question

Comment: @User image shows you added wrong header name `ContentLength` instead of `Content-Length`

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me and pointing me in right direction.Thank you so much.Appreciated